# Average per time interval by keeping the rows of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-preprocessing

This question concerns the dataframes in Pandas. Here is my problem.
I have a DataFrame of this format:

| Date | Weight |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-09-30 00:00:00.00 | 10 |
| 2021-09-30 00:30:00.00 | 12 |
| 2021-09-30 01:00:00.00 | 10 |
| 2021-09-30 01:30:00.00 | 13 |

I would to create a new column which takes the **mean over each hour by conserving my dataframe**.
The result should be like:

| Date | Weight | Mean |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-30 00:00:00.00 | 10 | 11 |
| 2021-09-30 00:30:00.00 | 12 | 11 |
| 2021-09-30 01:00:00.00 | 10 | 11.5 |
| 2021-09-30 01:30:00.00 | 13 | 11.5 |

Here is an example code:

```
timestamp = pd.date_range(start="2021-10-01T00:00:000Z", end="2021-10-02T00:00:000Z", freq="200L")
df = timestamp.to_frame(index=True, name='timestamp')
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df['weight'] = np.random.randint(1, 20, df.shape[0])
df = df.set_index(['timestamp'])
```

It creates a DataFrame like this:
[image]

Now, I can do a resample like:
 `dfresample = df.resample('8h').mean()`

which gives: [image]

However, this new DataFrame is reduced to 4 rows with an average of 8 hours. I would like to conserve my 432001 rows of first DataFrame **df**, where a new column **mean** is added, where each row takes the mean of that corresponding **'8h'** average.
How could I do that?

Thanks

Comment: how far does `df.join(dfresample, on='timestamp', lsuffix = '_original', rsuffix='_average').fillna(method='pad')` take you?

Comment: Unfortunately, not far. Since my real **timestamp** have gaps and also, you might not find rows of **timestamp** which ends exactly at *2021-10-01 00:00:00* like you find in **dfresample** (for example)

Comment: Was afraid of that...  retry, though I'm not very happy with the performance of this computational duct tape...       `joined = df.merge(dfresample, on='timestamp', how='outer').sort_index()` ; `joined["weight_y"] = joined["weight_y"].fillna(method='pad')` ; `df_fin = joined.dropna()`

Comment: alternative could be to create a lookup function in dfresample on index and apply that function..

Comment: Your **joined** actually works :) However, yeap, computationally, it takes some time. Temporarily, it fixes my problem. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2):

Better way, without `map`:

```
df['mean'] = df.groupby(df.index.floor('H'))['weight'].transform('mean')
```

or using `map`:

You can take the mean first,

```
mean = df.groupby(df.index.floor('H'))['weight'].mean()
```

and put them back in a new column

```
df['mean'] = df.index.floor('H').map(mean)
```

Comment: Thanks. This works fine :) Is there a better way to do this without actually creating **mean** DataFrame and mapping it back to **df**?

Comment: I am afraid 2 steps is the minimum. However you can save the temporary variable `mean` by combining these two lines of code into one

Comment: I was wrong. Please check my updated answer for without using `map`.